# Alter evaluation order when applying scalar multiplication to function

Tags: evaluation, hold

Consider the following program:

```
g = 2f;
g[x] (* (2f)[x] *)
```

Is there any way I can change the above expression to have it return `2 f[x]`?

With `Hold` construct perhaps? Sorry, I'm really not familiar with these `Hold*` functions.

I know I could easily define `g=2f[#]&` and it would work fine, but in my case what I'm really trying to achieve is something like that :

```
Transpose @ MapThread[Standardize[{##}, Mean, 2 StandardDeviation] &, xs]
```

Unfortunately, `(2 StandardDeviation)` is taken as a single entity. Having a whole `Function` would make it much more messy.

Comment: There isn't really a better way, just alternatives with similar level of complexity: For example: `g = (2#)&@*f` uses `Composition`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just settle for `Function[2 StandardDeviation[##]]`

Comment: @Kuba OK, I've added an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) as follows:

```
g = (2 #) &@*f

(* ==> 2 #1 &@*f *)

g[x]

(* ==> 2 f[x] *)
```

Your own solution using [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is of course also fine, and one could make it slightly more user-friendly by defining the corresponding scalar multiplication operation something like this:

```
CenterDot[x_, y_] := Function[z, x y[z]]

g = 2·f

(* ==> Function[z$, 2 f[z$]] *)

g[x]

(* ==> 2 f[x] *)
```

This would allow you to use [`CenterDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenterDot.html) to define similar constructs on the fly in a more readable form, by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> ot enter the scalar multiplication. So as an in-line definition this would look like this:

```
(2·h)[x]

(* ==> 2 h[x] *)
```